# convert json to csv using php not getting right format

Tags: php, json, csv

I am trying to save simple JSON data to csv using php. But the problem is that I am getting data in columns instead of rows. My JSON looks like: {"userid":"686868","deviceid":"dummy"}

and the code is:

```
   $csv_write_path = "test.csv";
   $json_str = file_get_contents($json_file);
   $json_obj = json_decode($json_str, true);
   $f = fopen($csv_write_path, 'w');
   foreach ($json_obj as $line){
       fputcsv($f, (array)$line);//tried using fputcsv($f, $line); // it saves nothing
   }
   fclose($f);
```

And the output is:

693936

dummy

But I want the output file to look like:
693936   |    dummy //i mean col wise

can someone suggest me that what possibly is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it an array of objects.

Your code currently is putting a line on each key of your single object.

example:

```
[
    {
        "userid": "686868",
        "deviceid": "dummy"
    }
]
```

then you dont need to cast to an array

```
fputcsv($f, $line);
```

Comment: can you give me an example, i am new to json and php

Comment: but the issue is that i need to pass simple information only i.e. {"userid":"686868","deviceid":"dummy"}, is there any suggestion on this?

Comment: I gave you the answer `[{"userid":"686868","deviceid":"dummy"}]`